# How can I link my web app in azure with MySQL data base?

Tags: php, mysql, azure, phpmyadmin, azure-web-app-service

I have created a web app and a MySQL db in Azure. And according to this tutorial http://ruslany.net/2012/12/phpmyadmin-on-windows-azure-web-sites/ on Azure Web Sites am not able to link my WebApp with MySQL db i.e Step 2 in tutorial.

[image]

Also i got this error when i tried to access my db

[image]

Comment: Not quite sure what you're attempting to do, but that tutorial is 4 years old and is specific to the old (*classic*) portal.

Comment: I am doing the same as given in tutorial i.e manually installing phpmyadmin in my website and linking it with MySQL in azure and am doing it because i have to give my db username and password to someone , so it would be easy for them to access from here directly instead of providing them my azure password ! :)

Comment: Still not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but this "link" does not do any magic and has nothing to do with saving username/password. It is just a logical/semantic linking for better visualisation. If someone needs access to your Database, you will have to provide the username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have not set-up phpMyAdmin correctly. The main reason you cant see the resource group in the classic portal is that most likely the phpMyadmin is created using ARM. If you create your webapp in the current portal (portal.azure.com) within the same resource group this will be "linked".

The login issue has nothing to do with the webapp.

edited thanks to @astaykov

Comment: Linking resources in the classic portal, as already mentioned, provides just a semantic/logical linking for visualisation purposes. There is no such concept in the "new" portal (portal.azure.com), and thus you cannot "link" a resources in the "new" portal. The "new" portal has concept of "Resource Group" which is the logic container for your application and all resources in the resource group are "linked", if you will.

Comment: I agree with you. By looking at @ashish profile I noticed English was not his first language. I used the terms he is familier with and tried to help him with his issue on what he understands. The portal is not "new", it is the current portal. MS is moving away from the classic portal. What I was trying to tell him is avoid using the classic stuff.

Comment: @astaykov !! ok i got it !! sorry for asking such a stupid question as am new to this !! Thank you all !! :)